# What do we do with the processed data (output) from Hadoop DB?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

i am a newbie to Hadoop, hence my apologize if my question is too immature.

I understand Hadoop is used for analyzing data on Large data sets.
At the end what we do with the analysed data, we create reports and presentations?

For eg, 
If in the case of SSRS reports, the reports will be generated based on the resultant data that is pulled from RDBMS using SQL queries.

But, how things work in Hadoop based DB? from a client if a particular report is requested, which needs data points from Hadoop DB, then how the flow would be?
i am sure Client will not directly run Job in hadoop to pull the needed data for its report generation, as hadoop job takes more time to process.

My question is, by running MR jobs on hadoop DB whether the processed data(result set) is stored in any Intermediate DB, like RDBMS? 
so that the client can pull the required data for generating reports?

Kindly clarify me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop have 2 main components

- Distributed Storage (HDFS)
- Distributed computing (Map Reduce)

Hadoop should be visualized more as Distributed Operating System with HDFS as distributed storage and Map Reduce as kernel. There are many tools such as Hive, Pig, Sqoop, Impala, Datameer, Spark etc which can leverage these distributed capabilities.

Once you run heavy weight data processing such as ETL, you can load data back to light weight relational database and connect enterprise BI tools such SSRS for reporting purposes. Also BI tools like Tableau have connectors to Hadoop via Spark using which we can report directly out of Hadoop. Datameer is Hadoop based visualization tool which can be used to report the data.

In short, one should not compare tools like SSRS with Hadoop. Hadoop is technology which provides distributed capabilities seamlessly and the eco system around it can be used to solve the business problems leveraging it.